# Help -- filling the forms automatically

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need to create a form for the field:

```
id
```

After entering the value for the id, the id needs to be matched in Database and the values obtained from the Database should be filled in the other forms.

i.e., the value of the title from the database should be filled in title form(input type="text") of the html.

this title field will also be present on the same page of the id field.

i.e., there will be a id field followed by a submit button after submitting the id the associated values of the id will be fetched and will be filled in the other form structures on the same page.

Can you suggest me how to do this.

Help appreciated and thanks for u r time.

Comment: Whats the problem? Why cant you just make it, you explained yourself pretty well.

Comment: Sounds like you need to assign the user a cookie (unless ID or any other info is sensitive) or a Session. I believe that is the only way you can move data from page to page via PHP. If the forms are already on the same page that should be easier to do with AJAX.

Comment: AJAX is the answer, unless ofcourse you want to do a form submit refresh page and populate those inputs with mixed html/php code but that's not the way to go.

Comment: What part are you having a problem with.  I see three parts to the problem: input form, getting result from database, and displaying the results.

Comment: This is all basic PHP/database operations. Ask something specific, rather than what boils down to "please write this whole system for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery.ajax` to perfrom ajax request, than render the response as you need. Here is an example:

```
<form>
<input type='hidden' id='id'>
<input type='button' id='fetchData'>
<div id='content_placeholder'></div>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#fetchData").click(function(){
        var id = $('#id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            url: '*backend url here*'
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                renderData(data);
                //This will remove this button, so user will not be able 
                //press it two times
                $("#fetchData").remove(); 
            }
        });
    });
});

function renderData(data){
    var placeholder = $('#content_placeholder');
    //...perform operations on data....//
    createInput('name_input','name',data.name).appendTo(placeholder);
    createInput('description_input','description',data.name).appendTo(placeholder);
}

function createInput(id, name, value){
    var result = $("<input>").attr({id:id, name:name}).val(value);
    return result;
}
</script>
```

In your backend you'll have to use `json_encode` to have data encoded in json-compatible way. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$result = array('name'=>'John Smith', 'description'=>'Unknown buddy');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for details.